# The right way to use a webkit selector with webkit gradients

Tags: css, webkit, selector

I'm using `-webkit-gradient` for text but it was creating a gradient block on the android os. The fallback color seemed to work fine in other browsers like ie without using a selector but when I did add the `.webkit` selector like I have below the gradient stopped working for all browsers. What is the correct way to do this?

```
div#item-header h2 a
{
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:#bf000f;
font-family:ImpactWebFont;
font-weight:normal;
}
div#item-header h2 a.webkit
{
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#D60011), to(#540007));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me: http://i.imgur.com/U6imV.png

Comment: ugh what the crap..so this is the right way to do it?